# Nested loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a program that uses nested loops. The inner loop should generate 10 random integers between 1 and 100 in each iteration and should continue to generate sets of 10 random numbers until two of the numbers fall in between 33 and 43. I want the outer loop to repeat 5 times.
Having trouble figuring out thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but it should be a starting point:

```
for ii = 1:5 % Repeat loop 5 times
    value = 0;
    while value == 0 % While loop, will keep going as long as that statement is satisfied
        nums = randi([1 100], [1 10]); % Generate 10 random integers from 1 to 100
        test_nums = ((nums > 33) & (nums < 43)); % Create a logical array which is 1 for nums between 33 and 43
        Tot = sum(test_nums);
        if Tot >= 2 % If the number of numbers between 33 and 43 is 2 or more, break the loop
            value = 1;
        end
    end
    disp(nums)
end
```

Is this what you're after?

**Edit** As I have now tested it. This is more or less exactly what you asked for, but it's really really slow. I'm not sure how it could be sped up as it's the while loop which is holding everything up, and I don't know how to improve it.

**Edit 2** Now it works perfectly - hopefully it does exactly what you're after.